# Error Cannot obtain Writer because OutputStream is already in use

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-7

I'm trying to send a pdf file to the front, but I get such error :

> Cannot obtain Writer because OutputStream is already in use
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot obtain Writer because OutputStream is already in use
>           at com.liferay.portlet.MimeResponseImpl.getWriter(MimeResponseImpl.java:92)
>           at com.netcracker.webportal.framework.portlet.decomposition.RequestMappedPortlet.sendModelAsResponse(RequestMappedPortlet.java:99)

This is my codes :

```
 try {
            ResourceResponse portletResponse = resourceRequestData.getResourceResponse();
            portletResponse.setContentType(PDF_CONTENT_TYPE);
            portletResponse.setProperty(CONTENT_DISPOSITION_HEADER, CONTENT_DISPOSITION_VALUE + "temp.pdf");
            OutputStream os = portletResponse.getPortletOutputStream();
            os.write(fileEntity);
            os.flush();
            os.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
```

The file is sent, but the error occurs.

Comment: Please provide more context: Which line is the one mentioned in the stacktrace? Where is this code that you need to get the portletResponse from some other object? Could it be that the stacktrace is triggered somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `PortletResponseUtil` instead. See [this example](https://portal.liferay.dev/learn/code-samples/-/cs/list/7.1/java8/workspace-gradle/modules/applications/portlets/resource-command-portlet/src/main/java/com/liferay/code/samples/portal/modules/applications/portlets/resource_command/command/XLSTaskListResourceCommand.java).

Comment: Can you provide the full stacktrace?

Comment: Where can I send it to you, there is not enough space in the comment

Comment: @ИгорьНазаров please edit your question and add the stacktrace there. If for some reason you can not do that please use any other service you can (like https://gist.github.com/ for example)